# Ending while loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm making a program for my assignment. This is not the whole program but it's just a part of it.

I want from the user to enter some integer values to be stored in "items" arrays. When the user input "stop" the loop should close and here is the problem.. when I write stop the program stops and give me some errors.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i=0, lines=1;
     int[] items = new int[100];
     int total = 0;
     System.out.println("Enter the items with its price");

     while(true){
          i=i+1;
          if ("stop".equals(scan.nextLine()))
              break;
          else
              items[i] = scan.nextInt();
     } 

 }
```

Comment: What are the errors? That's rather important

Comment: "some errors" - It is worth including these errors in your question.

Comment: There you go: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at mohammedkabbani_301502670.MohammedKabbani_301502670.main(MohammedKabbani_301502670.java:34)
C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation. The body of the loop is wonky.

Comment: Please don't try to comment on your own question to explain it.  Instead, [edit] your question to add additional information.

Comment: `nextInt()` gives you an error because with `nextLine()` it would have read and discarded any number you typed.

Comment: @Mick2160 and have you looked up what it means if `nextInt` throws a `InputMismatchException`? Everything you need to solve this is in that stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain mistakes in your code. It's more better if you could just add the error.

Try this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int i = 0, lines = 1;
     int[] items = new int[100];
     int total = 0;
     System.out.println("Enter the items with its price");

     while(true){
          String InputTxt = scan.nextLine();
          if (InputTxt.equals("stop"))
              break;
          else{           
              try{
                 items[i] = Integer.parseInt(InputTxt);
                 i++;
              }catch(Exception e){
                 System.out.println("Please enter a number");
              }
          }

     } 

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of other answers, I would like to advise you to change the looping from

```
while(true)
```

to

```
//first you need to remove the local variable i 
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
```

Using this approach will help you to avoid *IndexOutOfBoundsException* when users key in more than 100 integer values.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is this line : `items[i] = scan.nextInt();` because you are trying to get integer while the input is string `stop`

**EDIT**
one possible solution is that you get your data as string and check if it is `stop` or not and if not then try to parse it to integer like code bellow:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i=0, lines=1;
int[] items = new int[100];
int total = 0;
System.out.println("Enter the items with its price");
while(true)
    {
    i=i+1;
     String str = scan.nextLine()
     if ("stop".equals(str))
         break;
     else
         {
         items[i] =  Integer.parseInt(str)
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so what should I do now? I want from the user to input integers and when he finish writing the integers he should write stop to end the program.

Comment: I don't think this is the issue as `scan.nextLine()` will read anything at that stage, this isn't a `NumberFormatException` where there is problems with conversion.

Comment: @px06 you are right about `scan.nextLine()` but consider that in the code there is another line that is `items[i] = scan.nextInt();` so it will try to get input as integer.